# Stats not visible

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

We have published our app to the Google G Suite Marketplace.  The app is visible and returns in search results.  We see users installing based on http calls to our app, however, the Stats in the Chrome Developer Dashboard remains empty after a week.  The same is true when we look at the Google Developer Console -> Google Apps Marketplace SDK -> Usage.  There is no data.  Again, we know its being installed because of our own test domains plus seeing calls from other domains.

I am not really sure what else we can do to debug it.   It would be helpful to us to see the impression vs install statistics and also to see the uninstall statistics.

Thanks for any ideas ...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [post](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/161508/users-who-install-and-uninstall-immediately-are-counted-in-google-play-apps-dow) that can help you in your question.

> There are several pages within the Play Console where you can review
>   your app's installs, uninstalls, ratings, revenue, and crashes data.
>
> - Dashboard page: The Dashboard page shows a quick overview of several    key metrics.
> - Statistics page: The Statistics page allows you to customize more    detailed reports.

It was also clarified by a developer that installing and uninstalling will not change the number of downloads.

View these article for more info.

- [Quora - How does the downloads count for an app in the Google Play Store work](https://www.quora.com/How-does-the-downloads-count-for-an-app-in-the-Google-Play-Store-work)
- [Billions: How exactly do Apple and Google count app downloads?](http://thenextweb.com/apple/2013/05/16/billions-how-exactly-do-apple-and-google-count-app-downloads/)